# Allow vertical scroll in my website only up to a fixed limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, vertical-scrolling

I wish to give my users only vertical scroll and that too up to a automatically calculated height, not up to the entire length of the page.

Is it possible to fix the limit of vertical scroll that i wish to give to users. can it be done by jQuery. ???

Comment: Do you mean you want an element in the page to be a fixed height and have only a vertical scroll bar?

Comment: Consider setting the `overflow` css of your `body` element to `hidden` and the height to whatever you want the user to be able to scroll. I don't know why you'd want to do this, though.

Comment: @TelsaNick i am making a vertical and horizontal scrolling site. So, i wish to allow the user to see the content below one page which is infact another page only if he clicks the corresponding link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this part by hiding the underlying div and showing it just before I need it. So, I don't need to set the vertical scroll to a particular height.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a div with static `height` and `overflow-y:auto`

This will show the scrollbar only when the content inside the `div` goes beyond the static height

```
div
{
  height:400px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```